# gTTS Python Script in background getting tcgetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, text-to-speech, raspbian

Im developing an application on my raspberry Pi 3, using **gTTS** for Python:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import threading


def greet_thread(word):
    tts_thread = threading.Thread(target = greet, args=[word])
    tts_thread.start()
def greet(word):
    tts = gTTS(text=word, lang='es')
    tts.save("words.mp3")
    print 'Reproduciendo audio'
    os.system("mpg321 -q presilence.mp3")
    os.system("mpg321 -q words.mp3")
```

This works perfectly if i run the python script directly from a shell. But if i execute the python script in background using:

```
python -u script.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

i get this error in my log:

```
tcgetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

and don't know why. I think is the way it's called from a background process, but no idea how to solved it. Thanks for your attention and help

Comment: It looks like this library uses click. I vaguely remember click having an error like this a year or two ago. What version of click do you have installed?

Comment: @abarnert not sure if that uses click, pip show not find the package

Comment: @abarnet i changed the os.system for a subprocess, no error shown but the audio is reproducing in the analog output (jack 3.5mm) i don't know why. The Bluetooth speaker is paired

Comment: Unless this is a different gTTS project, there's an [`import click` in the source](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/blob/master/gtts/cli.py#L4) and it's listed as a requirement in the setup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the program needs to be executed using the same user that executes the GUI. So if you are going to execute it in a command shell, avoid using 'root' user.

In my case i need the program executes on start up too. So i solved it using "auto start" instead of a crontab

1. Navigate to ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi
2. nano autostart
3. Edit the file:

   @lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi

   @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi

   //your script.sh

   //or @python script.py

   @xscreensaver -no-splash

   @point-rpi
4. Save and exit
5. Reboot

Comment: I'm still running into issues even after running from autostart as you recommend. I've experimented from multiple Pi autostart tutorials to no avail. Can you provide some more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with calling mpg321 from a python script that was launched from a bash script via crontab on reboot. I was getting the vague error: `tcgetattr(): Inappropriate ioctl for device`
After digging thru numerous threads and trying everything I could, I changed  to use `omxplayer` instead and it seems to have solved the issue.
Best I can tell it was some kind of permissions issue with launching from crontab because I could run it without any issue from a terminal session.